# Login loop on Ubuntu 14.04. How to fix?

Tags: 14.04, boot

I followed literally every other Ubuntu login loop fix and none worked.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/hBUqE]
I think my professor said AIgLx is the error but I can’t find any info on that.

Edit: I have followed all the solutions in this post. [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: This loop is not the same you linked. Your issue may be video driver.  Ubuntu gives you some prompt at least?

Comment: Yeah that seems like what everybody keeps telling me, video driver

Comment: Can you do a recovery boot?  Go to fsck and do it. Maybe ubuntu will recover crashed drivers settings.

Comment: Command to do that?